# Get data using LINQ and show result in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

How can I get all modules from the array like below where student firstName, using Linq in C# and Asp.net. It's something probably easy to do but have failed to get the trick. Please help. Thanks.

```
ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();  //new array list for students
        arrList.Add(
            new Student
            {
                FirstName = "Svetlana",
                LastName = "Omelchenko",
                Password = "hh",
                modules = new string[] { "001", "002", "003", "004" }
            });
        arrList.Add(
            new Student
            {
                FirstName = "Claire",
                LastName = "O’Donnell",
                modules = new string[] { "001", "002", "003", "004" }
            });
        arrList.Add(
            new Student
            {
                FirstName = "Sven",
                LastName = "Mortensen",
                modules = new string[] { "001", "002", "003", "004" }
            });
        arrList.Add(
            new Student
            {
                FirstName = "Cesar",
                LastName = "Garcia",
                modules = new string[] { "HH", "KK", "LL", "OO" }
            });





            var query = from Student student in arrList
                    where student.FirstName == "Cesar"
                    select  query;

           GridView1.DataSource = query;


           GridView1.DataBind();
```

I want to put the results in a grid table in Asp.net. Please help!!

Comment: Hi, guys thanks for all replies, maybe my question wasn't clear in the first place, I would like to get only modules in the string array where for example Firstname = "cesar". And in the grid view, I would like only modules that are related to that username. 

something like:

             var query = from Student student in arrList
                    where student.FirstName == "Cesar"
                    select  Student.modules;

Answer (score 2):

you are missing ToList at the end of  your query.

```
yourGridView.DataSource = (from Student s in arrList
                    where s.FirstName == "Cesar"
                    select s).ToList();
```

then bind it to your gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid ArrayLists. Use List instead.

```
List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>(); /* ... */
```

And you query should look like:

```
var query = from student in StudentList
            where student.FirstName == "Cesar"
            select  student;
```

Then bind your Grid:

```
 GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `List<Student>` instead:

```
List<Student> list = new List<Student>();  
    list.Add(
       // ... Just like in your OP
     });
```

Then get the result:

```
var result = from student in list
             where student.FirstName == "Cesar"
             select  student;
```

You should then be able to add the result to your datasource using `ToList()` on the returned `IEnumerable`:

```
 gridView.DataSource = result.ToList();
```